# React - How to parse the array while fetching?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, express

I'm not getting the array from the **express** API.

In Express Code, It contains two Main **Array** **-** `headArr` **&** `titleArr` to **Send** as **Response**.

---

**Express Code:**

```js
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/v1', (request, response) => {

  let headArr = [{ head: 'head 1' }, { head: 'head 1' }];
  let titleArr = [{ title: 'title 1'}, { title: 'title 1' }];

  const data = request.body;

  if (data.term == 'head') {
    response.send({ data: headArr }); //sending the headArr
  }

  else if (data.term == 'title') {
    response.send({ data: titleArr });  //sending the titleArr
  }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

---

**ReactJS CODE:**

```js
function fetchData() {

  const sender = { "term": "title" }; //requesting the term title

  let result = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(sender)
  });

  let output = await result.json();
  console.log(output);  // Output: {data: Array(0)}. Not getting Array here.
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

---

**Console Output: FrontEnd**

```js
{data: Array(0)}  //I got the response. But not that array.
```

---

You can clearly see this here. I've got Complete **JSON**  response from the server **as** `{data: Array(0)}`.

How Do I Get that `head` **&** `title` Array?

Comment: I've also tried with: `response.json({ data: headArr})` . But still not getting that damn array

Comment: If you console.log(data) in your server code, what do you get?

Comment: I got this: `{ "term": "title" }`

Comment: I can't see anyway that you would get that behaviour. You should get an error for using `await` without `async`. You should provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your actual problem - clearly what you have will error before getting to the point where you have the problem. You might have removed the cause of the problem as well as the other stuff. You should also do more debugging. **Where** is the problem? Look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Is the data in the HTTP response correct? That will let you narrow the problem to the server or the client.